# Orthogonal Matrix Conditions

Tags: matrices, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

I am a bit confused about a matrix being orthogonal. A square matrix $A$ is said to be orthogonal if $AA^T = I$, and also if $A^T = A^{-1}$.

Now I was looking through the internet and found a third condition too i.e.:
$$AA^T = A^TA = I$$
I want to ask that which of the above mentioned condition has to be checked in order to find if a matrix is orthogonal or not? Can we use any one of the above mentioned condition or do we need to test all these three?

Also can the condition $AA^{-1}=I$ also be used to check if a matrix is orthogonal?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, they are all equivalent.
$$AA^\intercal=I\iff A^\intercal=A^{-1}\iff A^\intercal A=I.$$

Comment: But you should note OP's first condition wrong.

Comment: So I submitted an edit. Maybe it's a typo.

Comment: Saunders--- I agree that *maybe* OP made a typo. [your submitted edit may not get made for a while] (note downvote not mine)

Comment: so all three are correct?

Comment: Yes. Also note that $AA^{-1}=I$ holds for any nonsingular matrix.